# How to do form validation in JavaScript after Submit

Tags: javascript, validation

I want to validate my form using JavaScript.

For this I have created a function `validate` which should work when I click the submit button.
The message should be shown using the `alert` function but it is not showing any alert when I run it.

```js
function validate() {
  var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
  var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
  var cpassword = document.getElementById('cpassword').value;
  var firstname = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
  var lastname = document.getElementById('lastname').value;
  var cpasswordRGEX = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{4,8}$/i;
  var passwordRGEX = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{4,8}$/i;
  var emailRGEX = /^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/;
  var firstnameRGEX = /^[a-z ,.'-]+$/i;
  var lastnameRGEX = /^[a-z ,.'-]+$/i;
  var firstnameresult = firstnameRGEX.test(firstname);
  var lastnameresult = lastnameRGEX.test(lastname);
  var passwordResult = passwordRGEX.test(password);
  var emailResult = emailRGEX.test(email);
  var cpasswordresult = cpasswordRGEX.test(cpassword);
  alert("Email:" + emailResult + ", password:" + passwordResult + ", cpassword: "+ cpasswordresult + "firstname: "  + firstnameresult + ",lastname:" + lastnameresult);

  return false;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="validate()">
  <center>
    <h1>Dashboard</h1>
    <br>
    <label>First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" class="email" id="firstname" />
    <br>
    <label>Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" class="email" id="lastname" />
    <br>
    <label>Username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" class="email" />
    <br>
    <label>Gender:</label>
    <select name="" id="" class="email">
      <option>Male</option>
      <option>Female</option>
    </select>
    <br>

    <label>Age:</label>
    <input type="number" name="age" value="" placeholder="18" class="email">
    <br>

    <label>Blood Group:</label>
    <select name="bloodgroup" id="" class="email">
      <option>A</option>
      <option>A-</option>
      <option>B+</option>
      <option>B-</option>
      <option>O+</option>
      <option>O-</option>
      <option>AB+</option>
      <option>AB-</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <label>Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" value="email" onFocus="field_focus(this, 'email');" onblur="field_blur(this, 
           'email');" class="email" id="email" />
    <br>
    <label>Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" value="email" onFocus="field_focus(this, 'email');" onblur="field_blur(this, 
            'email');" class="email" id="password" />
    <br>
    <label>Confirm Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="cpassword" value="email" onFocus="field_focus(this, 'email');" onblur="field_blur(this, 
            'email');" class="email" id="cpassword" />





    <a href="#">
      <div id="btn2">Sign Up</div>
    </a>
    <!-- End Btn2 -->
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I edited your code and the error went away. You had some issues with multiline Strings, which are not allowed in JS with double or single quotes (`"` and `'`)

Comment: BTW. It's not a good idea to test a name field for valid content. In your case you only want characters and some punctuation. This won't test as valid for some Names which are of foreign origin (René, André, Jürgen, …)

Comment: Works fine on the embed example?